# How fft(x) works in matlab while N is not power of 2 (N = x.size)?

Tags: matlab, fft

How does `fft(x)` work in matlab when `N` is not power of `2` (`N = x.size`)?

Answer (score 1):

Works exactly like in the power-of-two case. The FFT algorithm does not change. However, has been proved that a zero-fill (i.e. append some trailing zeros up to the next power of two) improves performances both in speed (computational time) and frequency resolution.

The FFT is a divide-and-conquer algorithm, that is it works by splitting the problem into sub-problems of smaller size and then recombines the results. Due to this split operation, if *N* is a power of two, the performances are improved (i.e. it's easy to perform such splitting operation).
Performances are not that bad also if *N* is the product of several small factors such as 3 or 5.
Obviously, as you'd expect, it will be very slow if *N* is a large prime number since that cannot be split up into smaller sub-problems.

Regarding now the better frequency resolution, you can find some useful information in this tutorial [here](http://mechanicalvibration.com/Zero_Padding_FFTs.html).

Comment: so if a.size = 150,does fft(a)=fft(b) ?  %b(1:150) = a;b(151:256) = 0

Comment: of course not. In the 1st case you evaluate the FFT of` `a`, which has length 150. In the second case you evaluate the FFT of `b`, which has length 256. The size of the resulting FFT is the same as the input signal.

Comment: are the first 150 numbers the same ?

Comment: No. You can try it yourself by creating a 150-length random vector `a` and then creating `b` as you explained and finally trying to perform the FFT to both arrays.

Comment: ok I got it. Thank you very much